# Extract, check for duplicates and rename files in a sequential order from an archive in batch

Tags: batch-file, random, extract, archive

I have been trying to achieve in an easy way to copy image files to a server through ftp. Exiting files are using P123456 structure and new files should receive a _number after them like P123456_1. I haven't managed to make them go sequentially but only in random mode with the below code.

```
set work=%temp%\%random%-%random%
mkdir "%work%"

set archives=*.rar

for %%A in (%archives%) do (
"%ProgramFiles(x86)%\7-Zip\7z.exe" e -o"%work%" "%%~A"
for %%F in ("%work%\*") do copy "%%~F" "%%~nF_%random%%%~xF"
)

rmdir "%work%"
```

The above code would be suffice if the new files would generate random numbers for each file in the archive but if i have P1, P2 and P3 in the the archive the batch would output P1_random-number, P2_same-random-number, P3_same-as-the-first-two "random" numbers instead of P1_random, P2-other-random etc.

Comment: Use setlocal DelayedExpansion in your script and use !random! instead of %random% to use the value

Answer (score 0):

This is good example to describe the usage of **Delayed expansion** in batch files.

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set work=%temp%\!random!-!random!
mkdir "%work%"
set archives=*.rar

for %%A in (%archives%) do (
"%ProgramFiles(x86)%\7-Zip\7z.exe" e -o"%work%" "%%~A"
for %%F in ("%work%\*") do copy "%%~F" "%%~nF_!random!%%~xF"
 )
rmdir "%work%"
```

Answer (score 0):

implementing a counter is easy:

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set work=%temp%\%random%-%random%
mkdir "%work%"
set archives=*.rar
set counter=0

for %%A in (%archives%) do (
  REM you should delete the contents of %work% for each new archive:
  rmdir /q /s "%work%"
  mkdir "%work%"
  "%ProgramFiles(x86)%\7-Zip\7z.exe" e -o"%work%" "%%~A"
  for %%F in ("%work%\*") do (
    call :getfreename "%%~F"
    copy "%%~F" "%%~nF_!counter!%%~xF"      )
)
rmdir /q /s "%work%"
goto :eof

:getfreename
set /a count+=1
if exist "%~n1_%counter%%~x1" goto :getfreename
goto :eof
```

for a short demonstration of delayed expansion, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30284028/2152082)

Comment: Both answers work for first run but only prudviraj's version works for existing files, Stephans if i run the script twice (or by using prexistent files) the script doesn't do anything. Altough Stephan's script is closer to what i want i guess it needs an extra if file is existent add a +1? P.s. i don't know which answer to pick as the right since both are correct in another way :).

Comment: I added a check for existing files (see my edit) I had to do it outside of the `for` loop, because every `goto` would break the Loop. If you ran my first Version twice, the second run started again with `Counter=0`. The new Version should cover that (not tested!)

Comment: if no existing answer fully satisfies you, you could add your own answer and accept that.